# OpenWRT: What devices can support cURL on internal storage?

Tags: curl, openwrt

I'm trying to install cURL on my TP-Link `TL-WR740N` and there's no sufficient space for it.

How can I know which TP-Link router or any other OpenWRT supported device has space for cURL?

Edit: Is 8 MB sufficient? Or 16 MB?

Comment: It didn't work on TL-WR841N with 4Mb flash. But I remember that it wasn't short much. So it probably works on devices with 8MB.
I now have cURL installed on my device(Linksys EA3500) and have 24604 kB / 59124 kB (41%) used. So this is not an answer, just a guess.

Comment: @BenjaminH Your router has 64 MB of flash. That's a lot comparing with cheap TP-Links. Thanks for your comment, I also think 8 MB is sufficient but let's wait.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I should answer my own question but here it goes:

I bought an TP-Link `TL-WR842ND` and it has 8 MB of flash and it worked. So, 8 MB is needed to install cURL.